# $T$ injective equivalent to $T'$ surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm currently going through Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" (3rd Ed.) and struggle with the result of 3.110, where he shows that $T\in\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is injective if and only if the dual map $T'$ is surjective. He states in the proof that null $T = {0}$ happens if the annihilator of null T (i.e. (null $T)^0)$ is equal to the dual space $V'$. However, I don't see the connection here.

Comment: There are a few notations here that I am unfamiliar with. What is $T'$? What is $^0$? What is $V'$?

Comment: Sorry for this, I modified the description and hope it became clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $U^0 = V'$. Then $\dim U^0 = \dim V'$ and cancelling these in the equation $\dim V' = \dim V = \dim U + \dim U^0$ we have $\dim U = 0$, that is, $U = \{0\}$.

Comment: Got it, cheers!